# Path-Difference

Tags: vector, inkscape, text-on-path

I've been using inkscape for a few months and have a questions...

When I have two images and I want to do a path, difference, it does not work for me.  I tried grouping them and doing it and to no avail.  I read the above and tried, but still not happening.  Any help would be so appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please consider to add a link to represent the "I read the above" portion of your question. Text on path is not applicable to your question. Should that tag be removed for clarification?

Comment: Hi Kim, I have no idea what you are trying to do and what exactly your problem is. Could you [edit] your question to clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to check that the objects you are attempting to process are indeed paths. This can be easily checked by using the node tool (F2) and clicking on each object in turn. When clicked, you should see the nodes for the paths.

If the objects are not paths, you will not see nodes. Return to the select tool (F1) and click each item, then use Path, Object to Path to convert them. You can select more than one object by holding Shift while selecting, and convert them all to paths.

To further ensure confidence in your ability to perform the desired difference action, create simple objects (squares, circles, combinations), convert them to paths as noted above, then perform the action again. This should result in the "textbook" shapes and assist your learning experience.